# PS Csv Line count is null after import a one line csv file

Tags: powershell, csv

I try to import a csv file containing one header and one line of data.
The content of csv file:

```
hcode,scode,sname,Cui,Data,Denumire,Adresa
74489,!00001,tstvnd,19706741,2023-02-10,"test fiscal hist","Str. TEst "
```

```
$csvChkPrs= Import-Csv -Path $o_fsFileInput.FullName -Delimiter "," -Encoding UTF8
```

when calling the \

```
$csvChkPrs.Count
```

It Returns null.
I managed this as follows

```
$iRows= If ( ($null -ne $csvChkPrs) -and ($null -eq $csvChkPrs.Count)) {1} elseif ($null -ne $csvChkPrs) {$csvChkPrss.Count}
```

However trying to pass this variable to a function that expects as input an Collection.arraylist I get a conversion error reading that A PSCustomObject can not be converted to a Collection.ArrayList

I just used a repetitive structure to copy each item of the csv to he arraylist\

```
ForEach ($Line in $csvChkPrs) {$o_colChkPrs.Add($Line) |Out-null}
```

Any ideas how to overcome the error when getting just one line of data from Csv?

Comment: Because the input file _"containing one line of data"_ will be imported as an object that only has headers, there will be no data to do things with. Either add headers to the file of define them on import: `Import-Csv -Path $o_fsFileInput.FullName -Header 'Column1','Column2'` etc. Also if the delimiter is the comma, you don't have to specify that because it is the default.

Comment: The csv file has one header and a row of data.  updated the issue

Comment: Issue happens because in Windows PowerShell `pscustomobject` instances didn't have a `.Count` attached to them: `([pscustomobject]@{ foo = 'bar' }).Count` is null. Use `@( )` while importing your Csv and should be good to go: `$csvChkPrs = @(Import-Csv -Path $o_fsFileInput.FullName -Encoding UTF8)`